# Does a hybrid blackguard choosing Domination as vice gain the Dominator's Strike?

Tags: dnd-4e

Reading the compendium article, it's a bit unclear.

Comment: Ravn, we strongly discourage empty questions here. Can you please amplify your question such that you explain it slightly?

Comment: At the very least, if you can explain what makes it unclear for you, that'd help and we can address exactly what's going on for you. (Incidentally, [I just did exactly this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33703/1204) earlier on because someone explained what was going on that was having them confused, and it's a wildly different and much better answer compared to what I could produce if they'd just asked and left it at that.)

Comment: It's fine, I got the answer I was looking for anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the At-will you bring in from that side of your hybrid. Typically Hybrids get an at-will from each of their classes, the Blackguard doesn't get Vengeance Strike, instead he gets the at-will from his Vice.

If you pull this in the character builder it's far clearer. When you select your Vice it says "Level 1 At-Will Dominator's Strike"

Answer (score 2):

One of the Blackguard class features is *Vice At-Will Power*. This contains Dominator's Strike and Ferocious Strike. Hybrid Blackguards lack this feature, in my opinion this means that they can choose any Paladin at-will power. In the online character builder, at Powers you can freely select your Paladin at-will power, Dominator's Strike is not even a default.

Normally non-hybrid classes get 2 at-will powers chosen freely. Some classes restrict that, Blackguards and Warlocks for example do. You know this because the class descrpition says so.
Hybrids select 1 at-will power from each class. Some classes restrict that, Hybrid Binders do, Hybrid Blackguards don't. For Binders the description says

> Instead of choosing a 1st-level warlock at-will attack power, you gain an at-will attack power and a utility power associated with your pact.

If you do not find something similar by Hybrid Blackguards is because there is no restriction.

This has the strange consequence that Hybrid Blackguards have a better power selection than non-hybrids. Now you can dump Strength, and use Charisma as a primary, or use the various Domain feats.